# Ajax Style Loading Animation in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-3.0, loading-animation

I am building a Silverlight application around the new Navigation framework. Due to the nature of the application, there will be quite a bit of waiting around.

To that end, I'd like to add an Ajax-style loading animation to all my navigation pages.  In other words, while I go and get the data for any of the pages, I want to be showing the loading animation.

I can't seem to find any up-to-date examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to achieve this is to use the BusyIndicator.

You would reference this:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Then use the BusyIndicator like this (please note of the binding).

```
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="busyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding Path=IsBusy}">
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock >Fetching data...</TextBlock>
                 <Rectangle RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="#80000000" />
             </StackPanel>
         </toolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
         ....... XAML Code here
    </toolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

Then on your ViewModel you raise the IsBusy property whenever you would call a service to fetch a data or whatever process needed (I'm using the GalaSoft.MvvmLight).

```
RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusy");
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [the Activity control](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2009/10/03/silverlight-3-activity-control.aspx).